# Can I connect to a mysql database on another server?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a mysql database on a server for work.  I ssh ont the server and then enter the database using `mysql -u username -p` at which time the command line will prompt me for my password.

I'd like to access the database remotely for some development.  I see that `mysql.connector` is a library for connecting to mysql databases, but can I ssh onto the server *and then* access the database using python?

Comment: Is there some reason you have to ssh, and not just connect to the host via the mysql connector in python?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SSH tunneling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol#Secure_Shell_tunneling) to redirect a port listening on your local machine to a port on the remote machine.

```
ssh -L9999:localhost:3306 me@my.work.com
```

This will redirect traffic from port *9999* on your machine to port *3306* on *my.work.com*. We gave *localhost* to `-L` since we want to tunnel to the server itself. We could also create a tunnel through your work server to some machine accessible to it only.

Now you can connect your connector on your own machine using port *9999* and the traffic is tunneled to *my.work.com:3306*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tunnel.py code from https://gist.github.com/shnjp/856179.

```
with make_tunnel('me@mywork.com:3306') as t:
    mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                            database='mysql',user='root',password='PASS')
```

This assumes that your localhost doesn't have any application running on port 3306. If you have some, then you need to use "port=" argument in make_tunnel and provide a different port to use on the localhost.

Answer (score 0):

You can also connect from python to the database without using any tunnel.

For that, enable the mysql server to allow connections from the outside uncommenting and changing the bind-address line in the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file to `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`. After that, restart the server with `sudo service mysql restart` and finally grant permissions to your user to access from the outside `GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON your_database.* TO 'your_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_pass';`

Now you'll be able to connect from python to the database

```
import mysql.connector
ip_of_the_database = 'x.x.x.x'
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host = ip_of_the_database, 
                              user = 'your_user', 
                              password = 'your_pass', 
                              database = 'your_database')
```